# Using react-table with react-modal

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-modal

I am failing to understand why I can't use [react-table](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table) with [react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal) or [react-aria-modal](https://github.com/davidtheclark/react-aria-modal). When I try to display the modal, the component that displays react-table is constantly re-renders, and eventually crashes because of a `Maximum update depth` error.

I've created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-browser-vfp2t?file=/src/App.js) to illustrate the issue. Is there a way to use both components in the same tree?

The CodeSandbox doesn't show this error for some reason, but in development I also get this error (these stack traces appear to be coming from react-table):

```
(anonymous function)
/src/hooks/useColumnVisibility.js:207
  204 | 
  205 | useMountedLayoutEffect(() => {
  206 |   if (getAutoResetHiddenColumns()) {
> 207 |     dispatch({ type: actions.resetHiddenColumns })
      | ^  208 |   }
  209 | }, [dispatch, columns])
  210 | 

(anonymous function)
/src/publicUtils.js:153
  150 | 
  151 | safeUseLayoutEffect(() => {
  152 |   if (mountedRef.current) {
> 153 |     fn()
      | ^  154 |   }
  155 |   mountedRef.current = true
  156 |   // eslint-disable-next-line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to memoize the options, which react-table mentions [in some of its documentation](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/a474bc05fb6051dd144daf63125e2d8047993eec/docs/api/README.md#option-memoization). The options includes the columns, which you are currently not memoizing, so it gets new columns on each render (because columns is defined in the same scope as an array and `[] !== []`), and then re-renders.

The quickest way to fix it is to wrap your `columns` data in a `React.useMemo`;

```
const columns = React.useMemo(() =>[
    {
      Header: "Example",
      Cell: props => <span>no click</span>
    }
  ], []);
```

Comment: Argh. I did see that sprinkled around the documentation but assumed it was a pre-emptive optimization. Not sure how I feel about it *depending* on useMemo... Thanks!